# Make opening of cmd window optional in a tkinter app?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way I can make the opening of the cmd window optional in a python GUI app, like if option `xyz` is given, open an `cmd` window otherwise don't?

```
import sys
import tkinter
master = tkinter.Tk()
#tk gui stuff goes here
if sys.argv[1] == "console":
    #open cmd winow
master.mainloop()
```

I was planning to only open the cmd window if the user wants to see the debugging output etc.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum working example?

Comment: @merlin2011 edited

Comment: Depending on the command, `subprocess.Popen()` may help

Comment: no the console is just there to Show the Debugging Output of the tkinter app there and if the user doesnt define the console Option the cmd shouldnt even open @MichaelButscher

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows, you can execute `cmd.exe` with the `subprocess` module to start a Windows command prompt. It has many optional arguments which you can easily look-up on the web.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a complete solution, but it works. And is dead simple:

If you run the python script using `pythonw` instead of the usual `python`, it will run without a cmd window in the background.

For example:

```
> pythonw my_app.py
```

And if you want the cmd window open,

```
> python my_app.py
```

You could also change the extension of the script from `.py` to `.pyw` to avoid opening the cmd window.

Comment: yes but its about running the window or not via a command line Option like
python my_app.py --console

Answer (score 0):

you need to save your python file as a .pyw file instead of a .py
Note that you might need to copy the text of your program into textedit or Notepad and save it as a .pyw from there.

Comment: yes but its about running the window or not via a command line Option like
python my_app.py --console